# mod_rewrite for selectors with .html

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2, rewrite

We have a website where the URL looks something like,
www.example.com/about.smart.html

( "smart" being selector added on the app server based on the useragent if its a smart phone device)

We need to redirect the page to 404 if the URL is changed by the user as like below:

1. www.example.com/about.abc.xyz.smart.html
2. www.example.com/about.smart.abc.html

I tried with the below rule, but this redirects to 404 only for 1) and not for 2)

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)(-)\.html$
RewriteRule (.*)\.(.*).smart.html$ - [R=404,L]
```

Any pointers on this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)(-)\.html$
RewriteRule (.*)\.smart(\..*)?\.html$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: watch out for those dots, \.(.*).smart will not match the about.smart in #2

Comment: Thanks Jon, but again now Behavior is reversed. #2 redirects to 404 but #1 doesn't. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1720607 The first URL redirects to a 404 when I put those rules in a blank htaccess file and request `/about.abc.xyz.smart.html`

Comment: Thanks Jon, yes it worked. I had to rearrange existing rules.